i_<CTRL-Right> to advance WORDs (not words)
In insert mode, I want to move between WORDs (like normal mode's big W), so that I can save keystrokes. Specifically, inoremap kj to go left and inoremap lç to go right (ç replaces ; in Brazilian layout keyboard). This way I can keep my hands on home row.
There are i_<C-Right> and i_<S-Right>, but they move between words (like normal mode small w).
<C-o>W and <Esc>Wi work, but cause annoying screen blinking when changing modes (Insert / Normal / Insert-Normal).

Answering questions:

My goal is simply to save keystrokes when I need to navigate between adjacent stuff. I constantly feel that need when writing pure text. From what I understood about 'iskeyword', it would affect behavior of w/W and other stuff, which I don't want.

Line numbers and mode display blink here for anything useful mapped in insert mode with <C-o> or <Esc>, like inoremap <C-Right> <C-o>W. GIF below roughly shows it.




Optional info:
Plugins vim-numbertoggle and vim-airline are probably the ones that make screen blink.
Strangely, <C-Right> behaves differently in normal mode and insert mode:
<C-Right>   or                  *<C-Right>* *W*
W           [count] WORDS forward.  |exclusive| motion.
            If <C-Right> does not work, check out
            |arrow_modifiers|.

<C-Right>   cursor one word forward (like "w" command)   *i_<C-Right>*

There has beem some change some time, cited at changelog: :helpgrep Changed <C-Left> and <C-Right> to skip a WORD instead of a word.

Do you have screen blinking with <C-o>?

Could you tell us why you only want to move by WORD and not by word? Would changing the iskeyword option a solution?

Question edited with answers. Thanks!

Thanks! I have adapted the answer to stay in insert mode :-)

Do you still have something open in your question? How can we help you further? Otherwise maybe could you accept one of the solutions using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

I would do:
function! NextWord()
  let text = getline(line('.'))[col('.')-1:]
  let ret = ""
  let new = 0
  " for c in text
  for i in range(0, strchars(text))
    let c = nr2char(strgetchar(text, i))
    if c == ' '
      let new = 1
    end
    if new && c != ' '
      return ret
    end
    let ret = ret . "\<Right>"
  endfor
  return "\<End>\<C-Right>"
endfunction

function! PreviousWord()
  let line_nb = line('.') + 1
  let prefix = ""
  let new = 0
  while 1
    let line_nb = line_nb - 1
    if line_nb < 1
      break
    end

    if line_nb == line('.')
      if col('.') <= 1
        continue
      end
      let text = getline(line('.'))[:col('.')-1]
    else
      let prefix = prefix . "\<Up>"
      let text = getline(line_nb)
    end

    if text == ''
      continue
    end

    let keys = ""
    " for c in reverse(text)
    for i in reverse(range(strchars(text) - 1))
      let c = nr2char(strgetchar(text, i))
      if c != ' '
        let new = 1
      end
      if new && c == ' '
        if prefix != ""
          let prefix = prefix . "\<End>\<Left>"
        end
        return prefix . keys
      end
      let keys = keys . "\<Left>"
      if new && (i == 0)
        if prefix != ""
          let prefix = prefix . "\<End>\<Left>"
        end
        return prefix . keys
      end
    endfor
  endwhile
  return prefix . "\<Home>"
endfunction

inoremap <expr><C-w> NextWord()
inoremap <expr><C-b> PreviousWord()


Great! It almost worked here. <C-b> resulted in these errors: E899: Argument of reverse() must be a List or Blob E1098: String, List or Blob required

Thanks forvthe feedback! Could you tell us which version of Vim/Neovim you are using?

I have adapted the function to be compatible with Vim 7.0 :-) (the previous code was only Vim 9.1 compatible).

Great! My current Vim is GVim 8.2 and it's working now. Only thing is that, when moving one line upwards, it still blinks because PreviousWord() resorts to <C-o>B. I tried a recursive call - return "\<Up>" .. PreviousWord() -, but no good, because cursor position is not updated before making the next recursive call. I'll probably try to fix this some other way later. Thanks!

Thanks for the feedback! I have done the last correction to get rid of the last <C-o>B  ;-)

Hm, still happening when moving up one line. Maybe here: if col('.') <= 1 |     return "\<Home>\<C-o>B" |   endif

:-) I'll fix that one roo ;-)

This time I hope we have a correct solution :-)

Great, thanks! One more thing, I noticed now that column calculation is not working properly for special characters. This GIF shows it: https://pixabay.com/pt/gifs/vim-texto-atalho-15489/

Thanks for the feedback! Could you share the text you share in the Gif such that I can reproduce the problem. I believe I know the origin of the problem but to have an example will help me to reproduce the issue and to test potential solutions :-)

I have posted a new version that I suppose will address your multi-bytes/Unicode problem. Let me know if that solves your problem :-)

Almost there! I tried with this text: agora é definir que. When moving from é to definir, cursor stops after d. Seems to happen only when a word starts with special character. Last text was asdf não prorrogado çe, in case you need it, but that example is now working. Thanks!

I could reproduce your problem. I have proposed a fix :-)

Awesome, working great now, thanks! I'll edit my question to explain concretely why I wanted this feature.

Edited the code only to change endif to end, so it works fine with Vrapper/Eclipse

Thanks! I have accepted the change.

I used Vivian's answer as a basis and added regex searching. Changed also the logic to move between words like Ctrl-Arrow does in most GUI programs. Here's the result:
  inoremap <expr> ., PreviousWord()
  inoremap <expr> ,. NextWord()

  function! NextWord()
    let text = getline(line('.'))[col('.') - 1 :]
    let distance = text->match('\s\S\|\S\s')
    if distance == -1
      " on last word, or no words left
      let distance = text->match('\S\(\s\|$\)')
      if distance == -1
        " no words left; go to next line
        return "\<C-Right>"
      end
    end
    return "\<Right>"->repeat(distance + 1)
  endfunction
  function! PreviousWord()
    let col = col('.')
    if (col == 1)
      return "\<C-Left>\<End>"
    end
    let text = getline(line('.'))[0 : col('.') - 2]->split('\zs')->reverse()->join('')
    let distance = text->match('\s\S\|\S\s')
    if distance == -1
      " on first word, or no words left
      let distance = text->match('\S\(\s\|$\)')
      if distance == -1
        " no words left; go to previous line
        return "\<C-Left>\<End>"
      end
    end
    return "\<Left>"->repeat(distance + 1)
  endfunction


